# Saved my contacts in google account but they don't appear on my new phone

Tags: contacts, google-account

I have saved my all contacts to my Google account. But now in my new phone my contacts are not showing.

Comment: Can you see them on [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts)?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the following settings.

1. Your device sync is turned ON
2. Contacts are visible in [Google Contacts](http://contacts.google.com) web
3. Ensure `Settings > Accounts > (your account) > (contact sync)` toggle is ON
4. In `Contacts app > Options > Contacts to display` check whether Google account (youraccount@gmail.com) is checked.