# Retrieve my contact list

Tags: contacts

I am unable to retrieve my contact list,I had originally  put in on my Google account and only bits a d pieces  of my list  are showing up.have tried resetting my preferences to no avail.

Comment: refer this [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/155747/182055)

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the “Settings” of the device.
2. Scroll to “Accounts”
3. Select “Google”
4. Under the Accounts should be your Gmail address. Select it and verify that “Sync Contacts” is checked.